# Hiding/Showing Items clicking in ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, itemtemplate

I have the following code:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aprovar/Reprovar" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imbAprovar" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/Png0803.png" 
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirma aprovação do chamado?');"
                    CommandName="APROVAR" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("nIDChamado") %>' 
                    Height="30" Width="30" 
                    Visible="true" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imbReprovar" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/Png0798.png"
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirma não aprovação do chamado?');" 
                    CommandName="REPROVAR"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("nIDChamado") %>' 
                    Height="30" Width="30" 
                    Visible="true"/>
                <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="AvaliacaoChamado" runat="server" 
                    BehaviorID= '<%# Eval("nIDChamado") %>'
                    CurrentRating="3"
                    MaxRating="5"
                    StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                    WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                    FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar"
                    EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar"
                    OnChanged="AvaliacaoChamado_Changed"
                    Visible="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
```

What I need to do is hide imbAprovar and imbReprovar while showing AvaliacaoChamado when I click imbAprovar or imbReprovar. I know I need to change the `Visible` property, but I don't know how to do right here:

```
protected void GridPesquisar_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Change visiblility
}
```

This is very extensive and sensible pre-existing code that I don't have too much freedom to change without impacting all the system, and I'm still a beginner in ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the row you can dp:

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
```

and then to find the buttons and change their visibility:

```
Control buttonAprovar = gvr.FindControl("imbAprovar");
if (buttonAprovar != null)
{
    buttonAprovar.Visible = false;
}
```

and the same for the second button.